# Calling FMU's generated by Dymola in visual studio

Tags: modelica, dymola, fmi

If you create an FMU using Dymola and extract what is within the FMU, you would get something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOd7U.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCif7.png)

I used the following settings in Dymola:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiFYI.png)

The FMU is related to the following example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XnLb.png)

I created a MS Visual Studio 2022 project adding FMI2 header files:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jf2ZV.png)

I want to call the .dll generated above within C applications (to simulate the model). Anyone has done something similar?

I have failed to get this done so far

Answer (score 2):

A good starting point to see how simulate FMUs on the C-level are the Reference FMUs https://github.com/modelica/Reference-FMUs: please look especially at https://github.com/modelica/Reference-FMUs/tree/main/examples and the im plementation of the simulator fmusim https://github.com/modelica/Reference-FMUs/tree/main/fmusim.

(The reference FMUs extend the “FMU-SDK” for FMI 1.0 and 2.0 which is not longer developed https://github.com/qtronic/fmusdk, which contain also the implementation of a simple simulator in C)

Further resources (not developed by the FMI project) for simulating FMUs with C/C++ can be found on https://fmi-standard.org/tools/, e.g. https://github.com/modelon-community/fmi-library and https://github.com/NTNU-IHB/fmi4cpp

Comment: Thanks Christian for your answer. The answer is not directly connected to my question? The question is about calling FMU's generated by Dymola in C applications.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

1. I generated an FMU using Dymola (for x64, it could have been for 32-bit); I used the example Modelica.Blocks.Examples.PID_Controller.mo
2. Extract the FMU; you will see a .dll in something\PID_0Controller\binaries\win64; the name is PID_0Controller.dll
3. Open x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019 (need to install MS Visual Studio 2019 or else; but for me it VS 2019)
4. Navigate to the folder where .dll is located:
   cd something\PID_0Controller\binaries\win64
5. Run the following command:
   dumpbin /exports PID_0Controller.dll > PID_0Controller.def

This will create a .def file containing a list of functions. Edit the .def file as follows and save:

[image]

6. Run the following command to generate the .lib file:
   lib /def:PID_0Controller.def /out:PID_0Controller.lib /machine:x64

(For the step (5) and (6) I used the guidlines given in https://www.asawicki.info/news_1420_generating_lib_file_for_dll_library.)

Now I can link PID_0Controller.lib to a Visual Studio project. Make sure to add PID_0Controller.lib to Project Properties-->Linker-->Input-->Additional Dependencies:
[image]